# 2D array in Java with incremental column number that increase in each row

Tags: java

How Can I create a Java 2 Dimensional array whose output will be like:

```
0
0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

I know how to declare a 2 dimensional array.But don't know how to implement that. Sp need some help here. Thanks

Comment: What did you try  so far?

Comment: Note that a 2d array is just an array of arrays. Thus each "inner" array (which represents the values of a single row) can have its own length (you need to create them per row because of the different lengths).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is considered "row major", meaning that it does rows first. So if you know the number of rows you can do something like:

```
    int[][] myArr = new int [4][];
    for(int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
        myArr[i]= new int[i+1];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here no of zeros you want to put in each row is equals to the sequence no of that row eg 1st row has 1 0,2nd has 2 and so on. It can be done as follows:

```
int[][] arr = new int[5][];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  arr[i]=new int[i+1];
  for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    arr[i][j] = 0; //or whatever you want to store
}
```

Comment: In an ``int[][]`` all the elements are by default 0

Comment: And still I am allocating n*n spaces for the array.

Comment: @SchiduLuca it is true..but this way one can store whatever one wants in the array

Comment: @MdRahman please refer latest code..changed to jagged array so that you won't waste any space